# How do I get Elastic Beanstalk config changes to persist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My workflow is like this:

1. Create environment via `eb create` (i.e. the command line tools)
2. Notice that something is broken
3. Maybe change an environment variable in the AWS EB dashboard
4. Terminate environment via `eb terminate`
5. Maybe edit code locally and commit
6. Repeat from step 1.

And my problem is the intersection of these factors:

- I would like to use Saved Configurations so that `eb create --cfg LiveConfig` will work, and so that we can have one configuration for live, one for staging, etc.
- The dashboard only lets me edit the environment for running environments - so, even if I know I am lacking a key environment variable for the current code, I still need to spin up that instance to be able to edit it in the Dashboard, which wastes time.
- The dashboard will let me overwrite the current running environment (which is typically useless as the program has probably already read all its config data), but does not commit this change to the Saved Configuration that I used to launch this environment.
- The dashboard does not allow me to overwrite an existing Saved Configuration, meaning that instead of being able to edit LiveConfig and immediately relaunch with that, I end up having to assign a new name each time, leaving me with LiveConfig2, LiveConfig3, LiveConfig4, .. LiveConfig37, etc etc.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the limitation of EB.

Your best bet is to automate it with your own scripts wrapping the EB CLI.
Such as copying the configuration as new with changes, launching from that, etc.

What you are actually describing is closer to infrastructure-as-code. I'd recommend using CloudFormation to manage all of this for you.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-beanstalk-configurationtemplate.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html

Comment: I'm not worried about the deploying of multiple configured environments at the moment - I'm concerned about how arduous it is for me to have to work around the way EB forces me to change settings, save them as something else, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A saved configuration is just that. Its a snapshot in time. In order to "overwrite" your saved configuration, you need to use `eb config put cfg-name`.
If you would like to create the environment with extra envvars you can use the --envvar flag.

```
eb create --cfg live --envvars foo=bar,joe=baz
```

Or you can just edit the saved config before launching.

You can use `eb config save` to save a new configuration. You can also use `eb config get` to get the template, then you can edit it and use it for a create. Why do you even need the web dashboard?

Comment: "Why do you even need the web dashboard?" Who knows? Why did they put it there if it's not designed to be used? But what does `eb config put cfg-name` do, given that I don't have the config locally, but done via the dashboard? There seems to be a disconnect between how experts are using EB and how the docs tell new users how to do it.

Comment: Let me add one more thing - many of our environment variables are secret API keys etc. We don't want them checked into Git, but we do want them saved somewhere central - which makes the saved configurations the most obvious place for them.

Comment: @kylotan `eb config put` does require you to have the config locally. `eb config save/get` will pull down the file locally, but it will not get checked in to git. It also is saved first in EB, so other developers can still use it.